# Segmentation fault caused by libmysqlclient.so or libcofi_rpi.so

Tags: memory, mysql, pi-b+, crash, shared-libraries

Was getting a segmentation fault in a program that has traditionally run fine on most flavors of linux. Running ADB revealed that this seems to be caused by libmysqlclient.so using memcpy incorrectly, or from memcpy having some bug...?

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0xb6fd00a0 in memcpy () from /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcofi_rpi.so
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0xb6fd00a0 in memcpy () from /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcofi_rpi.so
#1  0xb6b8bf38 in ?? () from /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libmysqlclient.so.18
Cannot access memory at address 0x0
#2  0xb6b8bf38 in ?? () from /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libmysqlclient.so.18
Cannot access memory at address 0x0
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)
```

There are a few google results with similar keywords, but they all seem to be extremely vague or dont offer any alternatives/ideas.

Currently using Raspbian based on **Debian 7.8** with kernel 3.12.24+ on a **Raspberry Pi 1 Model B+**

**apt-get update** and **apt-get upgrade** are up to date.

Comment: What program is causing the error?

Comment: This was caused by EQEmulator (http://www.eqemulator.org)